# Java Thread synchronized Deadlock wait(); notifyAll();

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, synchronized

Since you are using a `Thread`, the code further below might give results like:

> ```
> waiting...One
> waiting...Three
> waiting...Two
> Notified...Two
> Notified...Three
> ```

Then the code is running until it hits a dead lock. Why is `Notified...One` missing in the output above? Needs explanation ... (You can get similar result as above when executing following code several time)

```
class A {
    synchronized void waitThread(String threadName) {
        System.out.println("waiting..." + threadName);
        try {
            wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) { }
        System.out.println("Notified..." + threadName);
    }
    synchronized void notifyThread() {
        notifyAll();
    }   
}

class T1 extends Thread {
    A a;
    T1(A r, String n) {
        a = r;
        setName(n);
    }
    public void run() {
        a.waitThread(getName());
    }
}

class T2 extends Thread {
    A a;
    T2(A r, String n) {
        a = r;
        setName(n);
    }
    public void run() {
        a.notifyThread();
    }
}

public class DemoWait {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a1 = new A();
        T1 t1 = new T1(a1,"One");
        T1 t2 = new T1(a1,"Two");
        T1 t3 = new T1(a1,"Three");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        T2 t = new T2(a1,"Four");
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply have a race condition. It's possible that the thread referenced by the variable `t` executes `notifyAll()` before the thread referenced by `t1` executes the `waitThread(..)` method. This is not deadlock. Some of your waits just happen after your `notifyAll()`.

Comment: But here first line of result `Waiting...One` already got. It is received since `t1` thread object executed. Therefore `t1` must execute before `t` and `t1` is in `wait()` state. But when `notifyAll()` executed means all the waiting objects continue. But it is not happened ...

Comment: But `waitThread` is a synchronized method. So how `t` object goes to synchronized `notifyThread` method while `t1` is in the synchronized  `waitThread` method.

Comment: @SandunMadola It's early for me and I'm not thinking straight. Simply, the `notifyAll()` happens before the `wait()`. In other words, `t` executes `notifyThread()` before one or more of `t1`, `t2`, `t3` execute `waitThread()`. This all depends on the thread scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the problem of [Spurious wakeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).So what is happening that the thread which is notifying the all other thread might be call earlier of other thread and after that other thread will run and wait for the wake up.Because of spurious wake up some thread complete.

Change your code...

```
class A{
     boolean flag=true;

     synchronized void waitThread(String threadName){
     System.out.println("waiting..."+threadName);
     try{
       while(flag){
          wait();
        }
      }catch(InterruptedException e){ }
     System.out.println("Notified..."+threadName);
 }

    synchronized void notifyThread(){
      flag=false;
      notifyAll();
   }   }
```

Comment: Spurious wakeup is not the root cause of this problem. The behavior would exist even if spurious wakeup did not exist.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ,Yes I know that behaviour would still exist but I am telling that other threads are complete sometime because of spurious wakeup and not because of notify thread.

Comment: Op should be aware of spurious wakeup but it plays no role in the answer to their question. This should be a comment.

Comment: Then wait u tinl you have enough.